# How to create singleton UIView with xib for using one instance on different VCs?

Tags: swift, uiview, singleton, xib

I have a custom UIView subclass, which has xib. I need to use one instance on different ViewControllers in my App.

My custom view initialize like this:

```
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commitInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commitInit()
}

private func commitInit() {

    contentView = loadFromNib(named: "ChartWithPoints")// Extension for UIView class, loading by name
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    addSubview(contentView)
}
```

How to change this code for singleton and how use this class after changing?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a singleton, nor do you *need* to use one instance for each view controller. Managing ownership for the one view is completely unnecessary. The whole point of a class is to have multiple objects. You don't need to have a singleton.

For each view controller, keep doing what you are doing right now and instantiate a new custom view per controller.

To answer your question about using the subclass, change the view property to be the subclass instead of `UIView`:

```
@IBOutlet var contentView: SubclassView!
```

To read more about what problems singletons solve, take a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) on it.

---

**Edit**

Since you asked about what the model-view relationship would look like, I'll try to give a basic example.

Say, on your view, you want to display the user's name and hobbies. The singleton model class would look something like this:

```
class UserData {
    static let singletonUserData = UserData()

    var name: String
    var hobbies: [String]

    private init() {
        self.name = "Bob Appleseed"
        self.hobbies = ["Swimming", "Planting Apples", "Drawing"]
    }
}
```

You will then be able to access the singleton via:

```
UserData.singletonUserData
```

In your view class, you may have some labels:

```
@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var favoriteHobbyLabel: UILabel!
```

Then, after initialization, you can populate the labels using the singleton:

```
contentView.nameLabel.text = UserData.singletonUserData.name
contentView.favoriteHobbyLabel.text = UserData.singletonUserData.hobbies.first!
```

If you wanted to modify the singleton's properties, you could change them from anywhere:

```
UserData.singletonUserData.name = "John Appleseed"
```

Comment: I don't need personal instance for each ViewController. 
I want to create instance once, and after if user changes any info on that  view, views on other ViewControllers will changes too

Comment: @GolovanovDmitrii Do not use a singleton view. Use a model object and have the view reference that object instead. When you make changes to that object, you can have every view update.

Comment: "The whole point of a class is to have multiple objects". Then why do Singletons exists? It isn't necessary to have multiple objects from a class if only 1 instance is needed

Comment: @tktsubota, that sounds like good pattern of OOP. If you will add some examples with images and code I will be grateful to you!

Comment: @J.Doe The fundamentals of classes are to have multiple objects and have them conform to the same "template". Singletons fulfill the necessity of a persistent, universal state that OOP would lack if they did not exist, but they are not the answer to most problems (see dependency injection), including this one.

Comment: @tktsubota, Okay, but how I can check if values of UserData changed and change label value in auto-mode, without programmatically handlers

Comment: @GolovanovDmitrii Take a look at Swift property observers or key-value observing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import  UIKit
import Foundation

class CustomView : UIView
{   
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel : UILabel!

    // Singleton instance
    static let shared : CustomView = CustomView.sharedInstanceFromNib(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

    // You can modify argument list as per your need.
    class private func sharedInstanceFromNib(size : CGSize)->(CustomView)
    {
        // This will connect your IBOutlet's with view's in Xib.
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomView
        view.frame.size = size
        return view
    }
}
```

NOTE - For first time when you use shared instance, It must be use on main thread, other wise Xcode's console will show some warning message.